# How to set timezone for Africa/Lusaka in Django with MySQL Database

Tags: django

I am trying to set timezone for my country Zambia on my django project.
In settings.py I have the code below

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Lusaka'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

And in my views.py I have imported timezone and passing it like so
`post.created_date = timezone.now()`. Regardless of the changes I make after doing some research the time is still 2 hours behind. Is there something I am missing?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes are first you set `TIME_ZONE` to UTC, and then to Africa/Lusaka which Django doesn't know hence invalid. Lusaka is GMT +2 meaning that the only valid zone strings are more famous cities like Harare, Pretoria, and Cairo.

Django has a timezone for Harare city so you use that as your `TIME_ZONE` value and delete the first occurrence. the settings should now look like this:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Harare'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the first

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

and replace

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Lusaka'
```

to

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Etc/GMT-2'
```

Comment: His comment was asking to set to GMT+2. Your comment sets it to -2. And the 'Africa/Lusaka' string isn't recognizable. this answer will just cause more supervision